# Technologies for centrally storing and publishing perl scripts and "small tools"?

Tags: version-control, catalog

**My problem:**

There are numerous (>100) tools the development teams use which are "home" written. They are sometimes a perl script, or a "web page", or just something that does a couple of small functions. I need to find a way (as part of my "Middle Manager in charge of tools" job) to collect these into a single catalogue.  None of these tools are "productised" in any way.

I need to be able to somehow measure usage of each tool. Uploading or submitting a tool should be a trivial exercise, as should downloading the tool. Must have version management and control.

Is there a technology for centrally storing and publishing these small tools?

Does anyone have experience of such quixotic ventures in other companies?

Supplementary question...

What sort of process checks are appropriate? Do you have a review board for tools going up on the server?

I want to ensure we don't have unintentional consequences from scripts. I also want to ensure that the "Business Critical" set are identified and maintained.

Answer (score 2):

We use a web-accessible front-end to SVN for 'field-developed' scripts, customizations, and small tools.

**addition**
What I use now is an instance of `trac` tied to `svn` on my web server. I don't know if [trac](http://trac.edgewall.org/) handles checking-in code as well - the version I'm running does not.

The front-end I referred to previously was in use where I used to work, and I don't know what it was exactly.

Comment: Can you recommend one to use?

Comment: @Dr J - please see the update I just made; sorry I missed your comment before!